# How can I get the default mode for c++ of g++ compiler without referring the doc?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I want to know the default mode for `c++` of current `g++` compiler. Except referring the document, such as [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-6/changes.html):

```
The default mode for C++ is now -std=gnu++14 instead of -std=gnu++98.
```

Can I get this mode from the `g++` command line? I try to look up this info from `g++ -v`:

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.2.1/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: /build/gcc/src/gcc/configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=https://bugs.archlinux.org/ --enable-languages=c,c++,ada,fortran,go,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-libmpx --with-system-zlib --with-isl --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-clocale=gnu --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libssp --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --enable-lto --enable-plugin --enable-install-libiberty --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-gnu-indirect-function --disable-multilib --disable-werror --enable-checking=release
Thread model: posix
gcc version 6.2.1 20160830 (GCC)
```

But unfortunately, this doesn't provide this knowledge.

Comment: You can deduce it from `echo __cplusplus|g++ -x c++ -P -E -`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use [`man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html), e.g.: (note default next to `gnu++14`)

```
man g++

...
       -std=
           Determine the language standard.   This option is currently only supported when compiling C or C++.

           The compiler can accept several base standards, such as c90 or c++98, and GNU dialects of those standards, such as gnu90 or gnu++98.  When a base standard is specified, the compiler accepts all programs following that standard plus those using GNU
           extensions that do not contradict it.  For example, -std=c90 turns off certain features of GCC that are incompatible with ISO C90, such as the "asm" and "typeof" keywords, but not other GNU extensions that do not have a meaning in ISO C90, such as
           omitting the middle term of a "?:" expression. On the other hand, when a GNU dialect of a standard is specified, all features supported by the compiler are enabled, even when those features change the meaning of the base standard.  As a result, some
           strict-conforming programs may be rejected.  The particular standard is used by -Wpedantic to identify which features are GNU extensions given that version of the standard. For example -std=gnu90 -Wpedantic warns about C++ style // comments, while
           -std=gnu99 -Wpedantic does not.

           A value for this option must be provided; possible values are

...

           c++14
           c++1y
               The 2014 ISO C++ standard plus amendments.  The name c++1y is deprecated.

           gnu++14
           gnu++1y
               GNU dialect of -std=c++14.  This is the default for C++ code.  The name gnu++1y is deprecated.
```

If you want to get it in command line (without a pager) then you can specify a pager for `man` with `-P`:

```
$ man -P cat g++ | grep "^[[:space:]]*\-std=[^s]" -A100 | grep -B2 "default.*C++"
           gnu++14
           gnu++1y
               GNU dialect of -std=c++14.  This is the default for C++ code.  The name gnu++1y is deprecated.
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only discover it from the manual/documentation for your version.

Of course, if you require this information, you're probably interested in compiling against a specific standard, in which case you're specifying your own `-std` value at build-time anyway, right? :)